# Count the amount of closed contours in an image - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, object-recognition

I am struggling to find a good contour detection function that would count the number of contour in bw images that I have processed using some previous tools. As you can see, my profile picture is an example of such images,

[image],

In this image, ideally, I wish to have a function which counts four closed contour.

I don't mind if it also detects the really tiny contours in between, or the entire shape itself as extra contours. As long as it counts the medium sized ones, I can fix the rest by applying area threshold. My problem is that any function I have tried detects only one contour - the entire shape, as it cannot separate it to the su-conours which are connected to one another.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting number of Blobs via MatLab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586464/counting-number-of-blobs-via-matlab)

Comment: so @GUY TALMOR did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my shot at this, although your question might get closed because it's off-topic, too broad or a possible duplicate. Anyhow I propose another way to count the number of contours. You could also do it using `bwboundaries` as was demonstrated in the link provided by @knedlsepp in the possible duplicate. Just for the sake of it here is another way.

The idea is to apply a morphological closure of your image and actually count the number of enclosed surfaces instead instead of contours. That might end up being the same thing but I think it's easier to visualize surfaces.

Since the shapes in your image look like circle (kind of...) the structuring element used to close the image is a disk. The size (here 5) is up to you but for the image you provided its fine. After that, use `regionprops` to locate image regions (here the blobs) and count them, which comes back to counting contours I guess. You can provide the `Area` parameter to filter out shapes based on their area. Here I ask the function to provide centroids to plot them.

Whole code:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Read, threshold and clean up the image
Im = im2bw(imread('ImContour.png'));
Im = imclearborder(Im);

%// Apply disk structuring element to morphologically close the image.
%// Play around with the size to alter the output.
se = strel('disk',5);

Im_closed = imclose(Im,se);

%// Find centroids of circle-ish shapes. Youcan also get the area to filter
%// out those you don't want.
S = regionprops(~Im_closed,'Centroid','Area');

%// remove the outer border of the image (1st output of regioprops).
S(1) = [];

%// Make array with centroids and show them.
Centro = vertcat(S.Centroid);

imshow(Im)
hold on
scatter(Centro(:,1),Centro(:,2),40,'filled')
```

And the output:

[image]

So as you see the algorithm detected 5 regions, but try playing a bit with the parameters and you will see which ones to change to get the desired output of 4.

Have fun!

Comment: Very nice my friend. +1.

Comment: thanks @rayryeng I wasn't sure it was a valid approach but that's how I would do it :)